# Familiars with max statistics

Tags: blood-brothers

I was wondering, when using familiars whose both levels are on max, you get anything when you engage in battles or not as they are on max? If this is the case do you still use familiars
Who are on maximum stats? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? What kind of things would you expect to get?

Answer (score 2):

When your familiar's level is full, it does not gain any further exp in either its attributes (str, def, etc) nor its ability points.

You gain nothing more other than the fact that it'll be more likely for you to win battles using a fully levelled familiar.

In story mode, it's a good idea to select your most powerful familiars as main with a less levelled familiar in reserves. Go through the map using the reserves as their hp re-fill every time they level up, which might save you some balms in case you need them in the future.

I hope that answered your question

Comment: As an additional comment, although the maxed out familiars will not gain anything from experience, they do get allocated a share of the total battle experience anyway. If they die during battle, your remaining familiars will get a larger share. But like you say, maxed out familiars can be vital to get you through some of the tougher zones